# How to control where the default namespace is added by the XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, namespaces, xmlserializer

I'm trying to control at what level the default namespace is added to the output of the `XmlSerializer` ...

So far I've got ...

```
<GetAccountDetailRequestStructure>
  <AccountRef xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/NAC/GetAccountDetail">4026069</AccountRef>
  <AccountType xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/NAC/GetAccountDetail">C</AccountType>
  <SelectionOptions xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/NAC/GetAccountDetail">
    <FromDate>2000-01-01</FromDate>
    <ToDate>2015-10-23</ToDate>
    <IncludeAccountSummary>false</IncludeAccountSummary>
  </SelectionOptions>
</GetAccountDetailRequestStructure>
```

using ...

```
var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add(string.Empty, "http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/NAC/GetAccountDetail");
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
xs.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj, ns);
```

but what I'm trying to get is ...

```
<GetAccountDetailRequestStructure xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/NAC/GetAccountDetail">
  <AccountRef>4026069</AccountRef>
  <AccountType>C</AccountType>
  <SelectionOptions>
    <FromDate>2000-01-01</FromDate>
    <ToDate>2015-10-23</ToDate>
    <IncludeAccountSummary>false</IncludeAccountSummary>
  </SelectionOptions>
</GetAccountDetailRequestStructure>
```

which I believe is an equivalent to the first XML example

Comment: They're not equivalent. In your first example, `GetAccountDetailRequestStructure` is in the global namespace.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever OK, if it's the global namespace, how do you control that in the XmlSerializer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the default namespace to the [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw0f5wee(v=vs.110).aspx) of `XmlSerializer` as well:

```
const string defaultNamespace = "http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/NAC/GetAccountDetail";
var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add(string.Empty, defaultNamespace);

// Note the 2nd constructor argument.
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), defaultNamespace);

xs.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj, ns);
```